# Celery sequential running incoming tasks

Tags: python, celery, task

I have one resource intensive task in celery. But user may want to run multiple of them. So I need celery to run it sequentially when previous finished.

I tried celery queue and task.delay but seems its has more than one worker so tasks start running simultaneously.

Example:

```
task_queues = (
   Queue('heavy')
    )
task_routes = {
    'tasks.heavy': {'queue':'heavy'}
    }


@celery.task(name="tasks.heavy")
def some_task(arg):
    ...

def run_heavy(arg):
    celery.send_task('tasks.heavy', args=(arg,))
    return {"status": "task sent"}
```

Celery.chain doesn't work for me either because tasks can come at different times.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the number of processes executing the tasks on a node by using `--concurrency` option while starting celery. To execute only one task, at any point of time, set this to `1`. You can read more about the concurrency [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#concurrency).

Comment: Other easy tasks have to be executed right after sending so I need more than 1 worker

Comment: Use combination of worker with `-c 1` and a dedicated queue. So if you want tasks to run sequentially you send them to that queue.

Comment: You can run different celery workers listening on different queues and different concurrencies on a single machine. Use `-c 1` for the heavy resource worker and configure other worker as required.

Comment: @LemonReddy the idea of duplicating celery workers sounds good. But I thought there is some way to do it on a single worker.